# Cannot boot Win10 from disk 2 while taking disk 1 with other Win10 out of computer. Dual WIN10 boot. Lack of EFI file?

Tags: windows-10, mbr, gpt, efi, dualboot

I have two disk at computer and I installed two Windows 10 operating systems at separate drives. Unfortunately after taking out disk 2. I cannot boot windows 10 from disk 1.
It looks like windows boot manager is only at disk 2, so it prevents me to boot at WIN10 from disk 1 (lack of EFI file)? Both disks are GPT.

How to repair this?

Comment: You will have to create the EFI partition on Disk 1.  What have you attempted to perform that task?  There is a great deal of documentation on how to accomplish that task.

Comment: Is it ok if I create EFI partition as third or fourth partition, not first in line?

Answer (score 0):

Only one EFI partition is required for any number of installations,
so the second installation disk didn't need it.

You will need to:

- Use both disks to boot
- Resize disk1 partitions to create unallocated space of 500 MB
- Create the EFI partition on disk1 as described in the post
  [Create EFI partition before installing Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1308324/create-efi-partition-before-installing-windows-10)
- Create Windows 10 bootable media using
  [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- Take out disk1 and connect disk2 in its place
- Boot from the boot media and do [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
- Disk2 will now be bootable.