# Why won't the Windows installer set up an EFI partition or boot entry?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uefi, bootloader, efi

I've downloaded a Windows 10 [ISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) from *[Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)* and I'm trying to install it on a SATA SSD on my desktop. Here's my intended layout:

- */dev/sda* (SSD)

  - */dev/sda1*: [EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)
  - */dev/sda2*: Windows (plus more partitions if it decides to create them)
- /dev/nvme0 ([M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) [NVME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express))—my board can't boot from M.2, so the EFI has to be on *sda*

  - */dev/nvme0n1p1*: Linux
- */dev/sdb* (HDD): Extra storage

My problem is that the Windows installer won't seem to create any sort of bootable setup on */dev/sda*. I've tried running the Windows installer two ways:

#### Whole disk unallocated

Boot the installer in UEFI mode. Delete all partitions in *sda*, select "Unallocated Space" in the Windows installer, and click "next" as [described in this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/clean-install-windows-10/1c426bdf-79b1-4d42-be93-17378d93e587).

When it completes the installation process, I see it has created a 16 MB "Microsoft Reserved" and a 232 GB "Microsoft Basic Data" partition. The result is not bootable (obviously, there isn't any EFI partition at all!).

#### Preallocate EFI

Boot the installer in UEFI mode. Following [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1308330/161008), use `dispart` from the installer to create a 500 MB EFI partition at the top of the disk:

```
select disk 0
create partition efi size=500
exit
```

Point the installer at the unallocated space after the EFI and click "Next".

When I do it this way, the final result is:

- sda1 - 500 MB EFI System
- sda2 - 100 MB EFI System
- sda3 - Microsoft Reserved
- sda4 - Microsoft basic data

In other words, if I start without an ESP, Windows doesn't create one.
If I start with an existing ESP, Windows creates an *extra* ESP.
*sda1* does not appear to have a filesystem.
The newly created *sda2* contains only `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/BCD{,.LOG}`.
I tried to open the log but it is binary.

I've also tried creating the installer in two ways: using [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) and following [this article](https://techbit.ca/2019/02/creating-a-bootable-windows-10-uefi-usb-drive-using-linux/) to create it manually. I can't use Microsoft's "Media Creation Tool" as I don't have an existing Windows system to run it from.

How can I get Windows to install and make itself bootable?

Comment: WoeUSB never worked for me. If you can, try asking someone to create the USB stick for you.

Answer (score 0):

The installation succeeded when I ran it with all disks except `sda` disconnected.

I believe it was [this issue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/cannot-boot-windows-on-primary-hard-disk-uefi): Windows tried to install to an EFI partition on */dev/nvme0n1p1* even though my motherboard isn't capable of booting from M.2 drives.

Comment: Re *"my motherboard isn't capable of"*: But another mass storage device's GRUB loader could be launched which could then boot from an M2 drive?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's how I eventually ended up booting, but I had to disconnect any extraneous drives to make the Windows installer create an EFI partition in a sensible way. I now have a motherboard that supports booting from M.2, though for some reason I still had to disconnect all but one drive to make the windows installer work.

Comment: Windows 11 install it's a big joke.... He overwrite any efi partition he see, so if you need dual boot system , first need to install this crap os, then other os you need ...

Comment: If you are unlucky and he see another system installed he will overwry efi partition which it's a joke...